# jquery hide div for each empty span within it

Tags: jquery, foreach, hide, parent

Basically, I have this dynamic HTML:

```
<div id="downloadSection">
            <a id="linkD" href="x.pdf"> 
                <span id="y">.pdf</span>
            File
            </a> <br>
</div>
```

Note that `<div id="downloadSection">` appears multiple times in the document and has different values.

I need to build a function that searches all these divs, and if the `span` within `<a id="linkD">` within `<div id="downloadSection">` has a 0 length, I want to add the `.nothere` class to the div.

I have tried this:

```
$("#postBody").each(function () {
                if ($("span#linkD").length == 0) {
                    $("#downloadSection").addClass("nothere");
                }
            });
```

, and only the first one is hidden. Note that `#postBody` is nesting this div.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of All, don't use duplicate Id's *use class instead*

**Html** -

```
<div class="downloadSection">
            <a class="linkD" href="x.pdf"> 
                <span class="y">.pdf</span>
            File
            </a> <br>
</div>
```

**js**:

```
$('.downloadSection').each(function(){
   if($.trim($(this).find('.linkD span').text()).length === 0){
     $(this).addClass('nothere');
   }
});
```

Comment: @pXL just a advice when you are using jquery then use $.trim() because .trim() is only supported in modern browsers

Answer (score 1):

ID should always be unique . having two  or more elements with same ID is invalid.. chnage your id to class and it should work

```
<div class="downloadSection">
        <a class="linkD" href="x.pdf"> 
         ....
```

and use class selector

```
$(".downloadSection").each(function () {
            var $this=$(this);
            if ($this.find("span.linkD").length == 0) {
               $(this).closest('.downloadSection').addClass('nothere');
            }
        });
```

Comment: i didn't downvote but you are using each function on .postbody and that is only one in the page

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I believe that this script applies the class to ALL the divs, not just the current one.
The last line should be: $(this).closest('.downloadSection').addClass('nothere');